# index was outside the bounds

Tags: vb.net

my code is not working please, help

```
Private Sub Form3_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        Dim lblControls() As Label = {lblName, lblID, lblGender, lblBirthDate, lblCity, lblContactNumber, lblAddress, lblHistory}
        Dim sReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(Form1.pathStorage & "Patients\" & selectedPatient & "\patientInfo.txt")
        Dim strValues(11) As String
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        While sReader.Peek <> 1
            strValues(counter) = sReader.ReadLine
            counter += 1
        End While
        counter = 0
        For Each lbl As Label In lblControls
            lbl.Text = strValues(counter)
            counter += 1
        Next
        sReader.Close()
```

Comment: It must be `While sReader.Peek <> -1`. `Peek()` returns '-1' when stream position is at the end and any  number when it can be read. You are reading from the stream even when `Peek()` returns '-1'.

Comment: Also your array 'strValues' might be too small or smaller than the number of lines contained in the stream. Better use a list of strings as this will grow dynamically: `Dim strValues as List(Of String)  = new List(Of String)()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed to the File class to accomplish your task. You do not need to declare an instance of File. A StreamReader needs to be not closed but disposed. A `Using...End Using` block or `Try...Finally...End Try` to ensure the closing and disposing of a StreamReader so the File class is easier to use.

You do not need to declare a size for the strValues because it is initialize at declaration. I added a check that the two arrays are the same size.

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    Dim lblControls() As Label = {lblName, lblID, lblGender, lblBirthDate, lblCity, lblContactNumber, lblAddress, lblHistory}
    Dim path As String = pathStorage & "Patients\" & selectedPatient & "\patientInfo.txt"
    Dim strValues = File.ReadAllLines(path) 'Returns a string array
    If lblControls.Length <> strValues.Length Then
        MessageBox.Show("Labels do not equal data.")
        Return
    End If
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    For Each lbl As Label In lblControls
        lbl.Text = strValues(counter)
        counter += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thank buddy but am not good in vb, o could you please help me further if post my whole code. thanks in advance.

Comment: No, sorry. Stack Overflow only addresses specific programming problems. You can ask more questions with the problems code, One problem per question. I hope you understand.